# scrollLeft() on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

I'm trying to scroll within my wrapper with `overflow:hidden;`, but it doesn't respond. So I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Each clickable element in the horizontal wrapper I give the function `imageSlide()` like this:
`<img onclick="imageSlide()" src="picture.jpg" border="0" />`

My jQuery-library is loaded and I tried to place the following script in the `<head>` and just before the `</body>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageSlide(){
        var $midScreen = Math.round(($(window).width()-$(this).outerWidth())/2);

        $('wrapper').animate({
            scrollLeft(Math($(this).position().left - $midScreen)
            },2000);
        }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

On request a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/76yar/

Comment: Provide a fiddle please.

Comment: What is a `wrapper` tag? A `div` with `id="wrapper"`?

Comment: I've added a fiddle, the wrapper is indeed a `<div id="wrapper">`

Comment: First, fix the syntax errors. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to see them. Then, `$('wrapper')` would select a `<wrapper>` tag. You need `#wrapper` to target ids.